# How is the "Normalized path expressions" option to Jayway JsonPath used?

Tags: java, json, jsonpath, jayway

I'd like to use the "Normalized path expressions" option to Jayway `JsonPath`, as illustrated by [this example](http://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/?path=$..*). The [documentation for `JsonPath`](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) shows this simple example:

```
String json = "...";
List<String> authors = JsonPath.read(json, "$.store.book[*].author");
```

I'd like to make the call

```
List<String> allPaths = JsonPath.read(json, "$..*", <option here?>);
```

and obtain the result as "Normalized path expressions" as illustrated by [this example](http://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/?path=$..*). How is that done, please?

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
import com.jayway.jsonpath.Configuration;
import static com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.using;
import static com.jayway.jsonpath.Option.AS_PATH_LIST;

Configuration conf = Configuration.builder().options(AS_PATH_LIST).build();
ArrayList<String> allPaths = using(conf).parse(jsonString).read("$..*");
```